# MongoDb integrating with external db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a database which contains data from two separate systems/servers. The first is generated locally [I develop and create this data] (users, activity logs, orders, ...). The second comes from a "product provider" [I only have READ access from API] These objects were created by MySQL and sent in JSON. They already have an "id" property.

With NodeJS, I use request to get a product by "id", and then store it with `newProduct.save()` appends an `_id`.

In products, "id" is necessary form relationships with the other collections in my database (such as products_price), and access dynamic endpoints, such as "products/:id/promos".

Note that products are constantly being updated externally and I need to be able to update my documents by "id" not by "_id" as the external server has no knowledge about "_id." [id is unique on a collection level, as each collection is a fresh iteration]

For my first question: should I treat "product.id" as a "regular" MongoDB field and use aggregate/lookup to merge documents from my collections? Or should I overwrite ObjectID() with id? (before saving rename "id" to "_id")

At some point, Orders (local) and Products (external) need to form a relationship where Order _id and Product id (or _id) are stored together for easy retrieval.

Which id do I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are pretty sure that 'id' coming from your product provider API is **unique** you better use that as _id  (overwrite _id), it will save you:

- an unneeded index ('_id' is indexed any way)
- some CPU cycles that mongoDB would take to produce the ObjectID
- some disk and memory space

(*) even if you find yourself dealing with many different product providers, assuming its one is using his own unique product id you could use a combined _id to make it unique as:

- _id = {provider: 'foo', id: xxx}
- or _id = [provider_name, product_id]
- or _id = provider_name + product_id
  etc. etc.

  *in this use case of multiple providers format depends on how you plan to fetch those products later.*

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Thanks for the interest use cases for _id